# Capitalizing subfigure specifiers

Tags: capitalization

I'm writing a caption for a figure that includes a few sub-figures:

> A duck (left) and tiger (right). (Left) The duck has wings and a funny bill. (Right) The tiger doesn't look like a duck at all.

My question: what's the proper way to capitalize "left" and "right" here? (As it is it's inconsistent, which is probably the worst choice)

Answer (score 1):

It's correct the way it is.
It's not consistent because **left** and **Left** do not mean the same here. "left" implies the figure on the left-hand side, which could have its own name or number. "Left" is now the tag/name of the figure, after the first mention.

There's a pitfall, though. Capitalization at the beginning of a sentence will conflict with this convention. so, do not use *left* after the first mention.

You know all this applies to *right* and *Right* as well!

Comment: I think you could just use the capital letters L and R in parentheses; this should usually be understood. Example: a tiger (L) and a duck (R).

Comment: @MilindGanjoo but this doesn't address Kris's point, which seems to be that capitalization should change depending on weather it's the first mention...

Comment: Well the point I was making was that you could just use those two capital letters L and R _everywhere_. Since these symbols only make sense in their capital forms, you wouldn't have to worry about whether to capiatalize further mentions.